# Why should I be punished for deleting my closed/protected answers and questions?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I don't see why why I should be warned about being made unable to ask or answer for deleting questions and answers I've put up when they have been deemed off-topic and closed, or voted down and become "protected" by Stack Exchange moderators.

Comment: It's to stop people hiding evidence. if someone makes a lot of low quality posts the offender shouldn't be able to sweep it under the rug like nothing happened. think about real life, if your charged with something and there is evidence are you allowed to destroy it even if it's/on something you own? (eg. terrorist supporting material or pirated content on your computer's harddrive)

Comment: I didn't know i was on trial. I was thinking i'd be doing the community a service deleting my own answers and questions that had been deemed low-quality and off-topic..But thanks for the heads up.

Comment: it's not that your on trail. some people when caught doing the wrong thing they'll conventionally try and cover it up and go *"show me proof"*. look at the CounterStrike:GO Lotto scandle where a couple of youtubers failed to disclaimed they owned the gambling sites the showed off. one went back though all his past videos and add the disclaimer to try and cover it up (but thanks to wayback machine we know this isn't the case)

Comment: it also just proves that should be common knowledge. everything you put on the internet remains even if you delete it. not to mention on Stack Exchange Sites those with enough rep can still see deleted question/answers

Comment: That is true i guess

Comment: You're only "punished" if you do it a lot. The occasionally deleted post isn't an issue.

Answer (score 4):

When you delete a question or an answer they contribute to a Q&A which can become more valuable than either in isolation.  These Q&As have contributions from others in the forms of comments, edits and votes, further increasing their potential value to the site.

As just one contributor to a Q&A, I think it quite reasonable that you are discouraged from viewing the deletion of a chunk of it as something that only impacts you. Doing that can  leave the remainder gutted which is why only higher rep users and moderators can vote for their deletion.

You can delete some of your own posts but my advice would be, as per the warning, to think about whether you really want to.